# What could be the Model Layer when consuming Web-Services and no Database in Django?

Tags: json, django, web-services, model-view-controller, django-models

I'm using Django as an application framework and it only needs to consume web services.

In this case, since Django is a variant on the MVC architecture (MVT, to be precise) should I wrap the web service calls into a 'model' that my App uses or should I just call those web services directly from the Django View and remove the model layer?

I want the model layer, data processing web service(json) that

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that many basic things in Django (like authentication) rely on a database; but as long as you are not using those - then you don't have a model layer as you are just writing a proxy to an existing service.

Your `models.py` will be blank, and your service endpoints will be in `views.py`.